# How do I make the slideshow buttons scroll through the images?

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a project and while trying to create a slideshow I found somewhere, wanted to edit it so that instead of using the setTimeout to scroll through the images or the circles, I want to be able to use the buttons to go left and right but just cant seem to figure it out.

Here is the link to what it looks like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-bash-ir9g0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, we just need to add `click` handlers for `left` and `right` buttons.

Below are the respective functions in order to display the next/previous slide based on the current index.

```js
//Handler to update the current index on click of right button
const onNextClick = () => {
  if(index !== colors.length - 1) {
    setIndex(idx => idx + 1);
  }
}

//Handler to update the current index on click of left button
const onPreviousClick = () => {
  if(index !== 0) {
    setIndex(idx => idx - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<button className="left" onClick={onPreviousClick}>&lsaquo;</button>
<button className="right" onClick={onNextClick}>&rsaquo;</button>
```

Adding these functions to `slideshow.js` & updating the `buttons` as shown will help you in achieving the expected functionality.

Here is the demo

```js
const colors = ["#0088fE", "#00C49F", "#FFBB28"];
const delay = 5000;

function Slideshow() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);

  function resetTimeout() {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    resetTimeout();
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
      () =>
        setIndex((prevIndex) =>
          prevIndex === colors.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
    );
    return () => {
      resetTimeout();
    };
  }, [index]);

//Handler to update the current index on click of right button
  const onNextClick = () => {
    if(index !== colors.length - 1) {
      setIndex(idx => idx + 1);
    }
  }

//Handler to update the current index on click of left button
  const onPreviousClick = () => {
    if(index !== 0) {
      setIndex(idx => idx - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="slideshow">
      <div
        className="slideshow-slider"
        style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }}
      >
        {colors.map((backgroundColor, index) => (
          <div className="slide" key={index} style={{ backgroundColor }} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="left" onClick={onPreviousClick}>&lsaquo;</button>
      <button className="right" onClick={onNextClick}>&rsaquo;</button>
      <div className="slideshow-tabs">
        {colors.map((_, idx) => (
          <div
            key={idx}
            className={`slideshow-tab${index === idx ? " active" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => {
              setIndex(idx);
            }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Slideshow />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow-slider {
  white-space: nowrap;transition: ease 1000ms;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slideshow-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.slideshow-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px 7px 0px;
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

.active {
  background-color: #6a0dad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

-- Update --

As per you requirement, if you wish to go back to the beginning at the end of all the slides, you can make the changes to `onNextClick` like below

```js
  const onNextClick = () => {
    setIndex(idx => idx !== colors.length - 1? idx + 1: 0);
  }
```

Comment: thank you that did the trick, one last thing i tried to just add an else statement to make them wrap  around so if we get to the last slide go back to the beginning but thats not working.

Comment: @JGuizar I have updated my answer, you can use the updated function in order to go back to the beginning.

Comment: thank you very much, your help is greatly appreciated i see now i was thinking about is as more difficult that it actually was.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by handling the onClick event
here's the link of the code [you could check this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-grothendieck-r41l4?file=/src/slideshow/slideshow.js)

```
import React from "react";

import "./slideshow.scss";

const colors = ["#0088fE", "#00C49F", "#FFBB28"];

function Slideshow() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

 
const handleChange=()=>{
  setIndex((prevIndex) =>
  prevIndex === colors.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
 )
}
  React.useEffect(() => {
 
  }, [index]);
  return (
    <div className="slideshow">
      <div
        className="slideshow-slider"
        style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }}
      >
        {colors.map((backgroundColor, index) => (
          <div className="slide" key={index} style={{ backgroundColor }} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="left" onClick={()=>handleChange} >&lsaquo;</button>
      <button className="right" onClick={()=>handleChange}>&rsaquo;</button>
      <div className="slideshow-tabs">
        {colors.map((_, idx) => (
          <div
            key={idx}
            className={`slideshow-tab${index === idx ? " active" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => {
              setIndex(idx);
            }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slideshow;
```